# Problem accessing the pages in Joomla based site

Tags: php, joomla1.5

Actually site was running smoothly till yesterday. But when I tried to run the site this morning the front-end throws this error

*Restricted access*

Moreover when I browse the administrator login page, it appears. But when I tried to access my login credential it throws following error though I haven't changed them.

*Username and password do not match*

Please help me with this.

Comment: I have this problem in my local server. I am using Wampserver 2.0c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you'll need to do is get back in to the admin to see if you can determine the source of the problem. Here is a quick way to insert a new super user account through PHPMyAdmin -

http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_your_admin_password%3F

This should get you in to the admin so you can determine if you've been hacked or something else has gone wrong. If this does not get you access to the admin, then I would recommend having your host rollback your account a day or 2 (you do have nightly backup with your account right?).

**EDIT**
Ok, since we can rule out a hack job and you can access the admin, now you can start eliminating the possible problems.

1. Switch templates to one of the defaults
2. Check the menu items, make sure none of them are set for registered access
3. Disable all of the modules
4. Disable any plugins you installed
5. Disable any standard plugins

If the site still has problems at this point, you can try loading another page with a component other than what ever you have your home page set to. You can do this by creating a menu item, then copying the link once it is created.

Once the site starts working, turn everything back on one at a time until you kill it. That will identify the problem.

Comment: Well actually I am practising joomla in my local server (wampserver 2.0c as mentioned above). So I don't think there is kinda hacked issue. Following your instruction I could access my administrator section but the front-end is still throwing the 'Restricted access' error. . :(( Please advise me. .

Comment: Hey . . Thanks buddy . . Your effort worked . . :))

Comment: well . . Actually, the component I was working need the system_legacy plugin enabled but I had disabled that plugin last time i shut down my pc yday . . And that small act made me crazy this whole morning :p